# How does python class initialized with different name?

Tags: python, wmi

Yesterday I had to use WMI for python project. I found python library [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html).
This library is really well documented and has a lot of working samples. e.g:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

for process in c.Win32_Process ():
  print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

or

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ("some_other_machine")
```

I was curious what kind of parameters can I pass for **WMI** class initialization and looked into the source code. I was looking something like ***class WMI:*** or function ***def WMI()***, but I found that it was declared like this:

```
#
# class WMI
#
class _wmi_namespace:
  """A WMI root of a computer system. The classes attribute holds a list
  of the classes on offer. This means you can explore a bit with
  things like this::

    c = wmi.WMI ()
    for i in c.classes:
      if "user" in i.lower ():
        print i
  """
  def __init__ (self, namespace, find_classes):
    _set (self, "_namespace", namespace)
    #
    # wmi attribute preserved for backwards compatibility
    #
    _set (self, "wmi", namespace)

    self._classes = None
    self._classes_map = {}
    #
    # Pick up the list of classes under this namespace
    #  so that they can be queried, and used as though
    #  properties of the namespace by means of the __getattr__
    #  hook below.
    # If the namespace does not support SubclassesOf, carry on
    #  regardless
    #
    if find_classes:
      _ = self.classes
```

as I see there is an explanation how does it work in the comment, but anyway I couldn't understand.

Comment: (remember that Python is case-sensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WMI` is defined as `WMI = connect` around row 1295 in `wmi.py` and is not a class, but another name for the `connect()` function.
So, to see arguments, look in `connect()`.